# Setting a number format pattern for a report to retain all the digits after the decimal point

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport, number-formatting

I am using *iReport* 3.1.0 to generate jasper reports.

For one of the fields on my report I want to set a 1000 separator pattern.

This field is in the *Detail* band and displays values with different number of digits after the decimal point.

So, I want to retain all the digits that come after the decimal point. (I cannot specify a particular number of digits in the pattern) Is it possible to write a number format pattern that displays all the digits after the decimal point?

Comment: What does it mean `all digits after the decimal point`? What result would be correct for the result of expression `1./3.`?

Comment: Hi alex, 
I mean, the number of digits after the decimal are going to be variable.. So, whatever number of digits come after the decimal point should be displayed as they are.

Comment: And what about the correct result for the expression `1./3.`? What will be a right result in this case?

Comment: I am not evaluating any expressions.. i am only fetching data from the DB. I am fetching values of a particular column from a table. This column has numbers with decimal points and the digits after the decimal point are variable. Hence I cannot determine maximum possible digits after the decimal point, that I can specify in the pattern.I want something equivalent to '*' in sql that will display all the digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put an *insanely* large number of #'s after the decimal point in your format pattern. Trailing zeros will not be shown, so as long as you have more #'s in your pattern than decimal places in your data, you will get all of the digits.

Comment: @user2195009 As GenericJon said, the pattern like `<textField pattern="###0.###########################################">` will be the good choice in your case ))

Comment: he he :) Good idea.. i'll do tht :P

Answer (score 1):

Clear pattern for desired field :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible. You must specify the number of digits after decimal point.

Identify the maximum possible number of digits after decimal point and set the pattern as #,##0.######## where number of # after decimal point should be equal to maximum possible digits after decimal point.

Answer (score -1):

1:- Start iReport and open the report.

2:- Select the field where you want to use thousand separator and go to the property section.

3:- Go to "Pattern" property and in number category check the thousand separator check-box.

Comment: The question was: `Is it possible to write a number format pattern that displays all the digits after the decimal point?`

Comment: yes Sharad, i have added the 1000 separator but the 1000 separator sets the pattern as '#,##0.00' where '.00' represent the number of digits after the decimal point. But in my case, the number of digits after the decimal point are variable.. so I need a pattern that can display any number of digits after the decimal point.. e.g. if the number has 2 digits after the decimal point it should display 2 , if it has 5 digits , it should display 5.. like this..

Comment: Hi Avinash,
I cannot identify the maximum possible digits.Tht's why I want to display the digits as they come.Like in sql query when we say 'select * ' all the columns get selected.. Isn't there anything equivalent to '*' in number format patterns?

Comment: I dont think so its possible.